# Will JavaFX work on Android?

Tags: android, javafx

It would be a shame if it doesn't, because it will make for more attractive looking Android applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not right now, and it would be a nontrivial task to make it work. Android doesn't have all the libraries that the typical desktop JRE does. Although since Android is open source and it will run anything that can be compiled to Dalvik byte code, it's not impossible.

Really, I don't really think JavaFX will make for more attractive looking Android applications - the most important thing is how integrated the application is into the hardware and the Android display framework has a lot of stuff to make that easier.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX 2.0 is now a library. The implementations are platform specific because, amongst others, of the use of hardware accelerated graphics. There's a version for Windows (that uses *DirectX*) and a developer preview for Linux and Mac (which uses *OpenGL*) : [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html)

Because of the heavy use of hardware acceleration, I guess if there will be an android version (very likely), the target will be relatively new tables, rather then all android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's not so important the attractiveness. I think portability matters a lot nowadays, and this kind of tech makes it very portable.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below link : [openjdk](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Cross+Building+for+Android) , [oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/jfxprg/entry/javafx_on_android)