# 3D Scene graph toolkits for Android

Tags: android, scenegraph

I was wondering if there is any 3D scene graph toolkit available or at least in development for Android? I could not find anything, assuming that all existing solutions for Java won't run on the Android platform.

Answer (score 3):

I played around with the simple but quite powerful JPCT library that is supported by quite an active forum. The author has ported the libary to Android, and shows some nice demos on his site.

http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae

Comment: Unfortunately JPCT is closed source. If there are bugs, you'll have to wait until the author fixes them. If the author loses interest or decides to go commercial, your only option is to search for another library and port your project.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into JMonkey Engine.  They are working on an Android version:

http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/forum/index.php?topic=13643.0
http://jmonkeyengine.com/blog/blog/2010/02/10/android-support-confirmed-for-jme3/

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried out JavaFX Mobile?  http://java.sun.com/javafx/index.jsp

Comment: JavaFX does not currently run on Android (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240469/will-javafx-work-on-android)

Answer (score -2):

I'm looking for one as well. I came across this today, but I have no idea if its actually any good -- the company site looks kinda sketchy!!

http://www.artfulbits.com/Android/aiCharts.aspx

Comment: The OP is asking about a [3D scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph), not charts.